# PHP get_class() functionality in child classes

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I need to check if a property exists and this works:

```
class someClass {
  protected $some_var

  public static function checkProperty($property) {
    if(!property_exists(get_class()) ) {
      return true;
    } else return false;
  }
}
```

But now when I try to extend the class, it doesn't work anymore.

```
class someChild extends someClass {
  protected $child_property;

}


someChild::checkProperty('child_property'); // false
```

How do I get the functionality I want? I tried replacing `get_class()` with `$this`, `self`, `static`, nothing works.

Comment: @Fluffeh I clicked the code brackets for my code sections but it didn't work. It hasn't been working lately for me.

Comment: I thought the code button did the same thing as indenting. Maybe there is some bug with SO and google chrome browser.

Comment: Did you forget to use the _extends_ statement? See http://php.net/manual/de/keyword.extends.php

Comment: @PhilippGrassl no I didn't. I just forgot to put it into the question. Fixed. I would have gotten a fatal error for trying to access a non-existent method if I hadn't put in the 'extends'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've found the correct answer. For static methods, use `get_called_class()`.

Perhaps `$this` works for object methods.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking property_exists against get_class() and get_parent_class()? However, for more nested classes you would have to check against the classes recursively.

```
public static function checkProperty($property)
{
    if (property_exists(get_class(), $property)
        or property_exists(get_parent_class(), $property))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

(sorry but I'm more into Allman-Style ;-))

Comment: I'm pretty sure `get_called_class()` is the correct way to do it. It seems to be working anyway. Only available in PHP 5.3+ I believe.

Comment: Woops, didn't see, you answered your own question. Please accept your answer. ;)

Answer (score -1):

The following works:

```
<?php

class Car
{
    protected $_var;

    public function checkProperty($propertyName)
    {
        if (!property_exists($this, $propertyName)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

class BMW extends Car
{
    protected $_prop;
}

$bmw = new BMW();
var_dump($bmw->checkProperty('_prop'));
```

> @param $class The class name or an object of the class to test for

Comment: Wonderful, except that I am asking about static methods and this answer is useless.